# Automate gitlab updates from one gitlab instance to another

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

### My situation

I have 2 self-managed GitLab instances. One is the one that has all the work in it and the second is a new one that I created as a backup plan if something happened to the first one.

To copy all projects from the first GitLab to the other I backed it up and restored it in the second GitLab.

### My Problem

I want the changes and updates in the first GitLab to be updated in the second one automatically. Does anyone have any ideas on how can I do that?

Comment: you could write a script to swap the remotes and push.. but why create a second instance to automatically push to? surely whatever you're trying to protect from incurred in the first would then occur in the second

Comment: the instances are vms , i had a problem this week the vm got deleted because we had disks problem (fortunately i had a backup of the vm)

Comment: i want to have  vms in  diffrent disks so if something happend to a certan disk

Comment: I'd start with the documentation Gitlab provides for [High Availability](https://docs.gitlab.com/12.10/ee/administration/availability/index.html), and come back to ask any specific questions you have on the implementation. High Availability will keep all systems up to date automatically, and will provide automatic failover in the event that the primary system fails so you can keep using it in the event of an outage.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a few repos then I would suggest [repository mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html). If you have several repositories then Adam Marshall's comment about HA would be the best approach.

Comment: the problem of repository mirroring is my 2 instances are in a local network and it looks like local repos are not supported